# Prevent python performing string interpolation (replacement) with %s inside sqlite3 SQL block

Tags: python, sqlite, escaping, string-interpolation

So here's the line with the SQL query in it. How do I use strftime('%s', 'now') without python trying to replace %s with a string... this is incredibly annoying.

Thanks

```
DBQuery.query('INSERT INTO test (Date, Entry) VALUES (strftime(''%ss'', ''now''), "%s")' %('%', cherrypy.request.params['username']), 'INSERT')
```

Comment: What is your desired output you want to pass to the db?

Comment: `execute(... ...VALUES (strftime('%s', 'now'), ?))", cherrpy.request.params['username'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just escape the `%` by using two back to back, so put `%%s` in the string where you want it to become `%s`.  For example:

```
>>> print '''strftime('%%s', 'now'), "%s"''' % "some value"
strftime('%s', 'now'), "some value"
```

Also, I don't think your back to back single quotes are doing what you think they are.  This will not leave a single quote in the string, it will just concatenate the two strings together, for example:

```
>>> 'aaa''bbb'
'aaabbb'
```

Instead you should use triple quoted strings or escape the single quote.  End result might look something like this:

```
DBQuery.query('''INSERT INTO test (Date, Entry) VALUES (strftime('%%s', 'now'), "%s")''' % cherrypy.request.params['username'], 'INSERT')
```

Comment: Triple quoting in double quotes prevented the string interpolation being performed so `'%s'` by istelf then was passed to strftime correctly. Also I am now using `execute(query, params)` where query contains `?` placeholders and params is a tuple. Thanks for the help nonetheless.